# Calculating a definite integral with complex limit - proof verification

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals, complex-numbers

> Calculate: $\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi/2+i}\cos(2z)dz$

My solution:

$\cos(2z)$ is analytic throughout $\mathbb{C}$ and therefore the definite integral is independent of the choice of path. We then have:

$$\begin{align}\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi/2+i}\cos(2z)dz &=\frac{\sin(2z)}{2}|_{\pi/2}^{\pi/2+i}\\ &=\frac{\sin(\pi+2i)}{2}-\frac{\sin(\pi)}{2}\\ &=\frac{(e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2i)}-e^{-i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2i)})}{4i}\\ &=\frac{e^{i\pi/2}e^{2}(e^{-4}-e^{-i\pi})}{4i}\\ &=\frac{ie^2(e^{-4}+1)}{4i}\\ &=\frac{e^{2}+e^{-2}}{4}=\frac{\cos(2i)}{2}\end{align}$$

Is my calculation correct? The main thing is I'm not definitely sure how to approach complex integrals with complex numbers as limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost correct. You have\begin{align}\require{cancel}\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi/2+i}\cos(2z)\,\mathrm dz&=\left.\frac{\sin(2z)}2\right|_{\pi/2}^{\pi/2+i}\\&=\frac{\sin(\pi+2i)}2-\cancel{\frac{\sin(\pi)}2}\\&=-\frac{\sin(2i)}2\end{align}since $(\forall z\in\Bbb C):\sin(\pi+z)=-\sin(z)$.